# SQL Query to identify records missing a value from an array

Tags: sql-server

I have a table, it has the fields: ID, Program

Example table:

```
ID    Program
-----------------
1  office
1  internet explorer
1  Antivirus
2  office
2  internet explorer
2  messenger
2  bitcoin
3  office
3  internet explorer
3  Antivirus
```

I need to know how to construct a query to pull the ID's that do not contain a row program value Antivirus. So a query against the example should return ID 2

This is for a MS SQL server. I am guessing I want to do some sort of loop search for each ID.

Comment: `select * from example where program <> 'antivirus'`

Comment: @SouXin this would return 1,2, and 3 [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4241ba63e1466d23d9dcff3d9ed307c2).

Comment: @AlexKudryashev this would return data for all ID's in the current result set (just excluding a couple of rows) [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4241ba63e1466d23d9dcff3d9ed307c2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is `NOT IN`.

```
select distinct id
from example
where id not in (select id from example where program = 'antivirus')
```

Another is `NOT EXISTS`

```
select distinct e1.id
from example e1
where not exists (select 1 from example e2 where e2.program = 'antivirus' and e2.id = e1.id )
```

Also, a comment on looping in SQL Server. Generally speaking, you want to avoid loops at all costs. SQL Server works best in sets, and any loop or iterative process will not perform well in SQL Server.

Comment: what is the purpose to adding `and e2.id = e1.id`  in the second query ?

Comment: It's to correlate the outer query to the inner query @sayahimad

Comment: I'm confused to your comment @sayahimad but this would return no rows.